# React: Anchor tags in website not rendering in safari. Works on other browsers (Chrome,Edge)

Tags: html, reactjs, safari, react-router, anchor

```
 <Row style={{padding:"2% 15%",alignItems:"center",textAlign:"center"}}>
                    <Col xs="12" lg="4"  className="column-space text-center zoom ">
                        <a href="#link1" style={{padding:"3% 20%"}} className="mont-med text-center column-yellow">
                            link1
                    </a>
                </Col>
                
                <Col xs="12"  lg="4" className="column-space text-center zoom ">
                    <a href="#link2"  style={{padding:"3% 20%"}} className="mont-med text-center column-red">
                        link2
                    </a>
                </Col>
                
                <Col xs="12"  lg="4" className="column-space text-center zoom ">
                    <a href="#link3" style={{padding:"3% 35%"}}  className="mont-med text-center column-green">
                        link3
                    </a>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row style={{padding:"0% 30%",alignItems:"center",textAlign:"center"}}>
                <Col xs="12" lg="6" style={{textAlign:"right"}} className="column-space text-center zoom">
                    <a href="#link4" style={{padding:"3% 20%"}}  className="mont-med text-center column-green">
                        link4
                    </a>

                </Col>
                <Col xs="12" lg="6" className="column-space text-center zoom">
                    <Link to="/link5">
                    <Button className="mont-med text-center column-yellow">
                      link5
                    </Button>
                    </Link>
                </Col>
            </Row>
```

I have tried adding / before tag like "http://example.com/product/#link1" as suggested by other answers but didnt work.

On clicking these links the page scrolls to top instead of the required div element

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I found HashLink-  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link to work just fine for my use case. I used hashlinks instead of anchor tags and that solved the problem for me. Please ping if someone still knows the reason behind such behavior of safari.

Comment: I'm having close to the same issue... For safari it seems that Link from next.js work but NOT anchor tags.